# Insert values into dynamically created table in the same stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

My task is: create a table and insert n values into the table in the same stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC
    @tableName nvarchar(30),
    @nRows          int
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
                 AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[@tableName ]

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName +
                     '(
                          [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                          [col1] [int] NOT NULL
                      ); GO';

    EXEC (@SQLString);

    DECLARE @i int = 1;

    WHILE (@i <= @nRows)
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;

        INSERT INTO @tableName values (@i);
    END
END
```

I know the problem is that the table does not exist until commit; and that's why I cannot insert. But how to rewrite this to be able to do my task?

Comment: There are several issues here. First you need to wrap your table variable with Quotename to help prevent sql injection, or if the value includes spaces or other characters that would require the usage of square brackets. Then you need to use a numbers or tally table instead of looping to insert a bunch of integers. The insert will have to be done with dynamic sql also, you can't do an insert like you are with a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserts should be dynamic. Use `sp_executesql`:

```
....

EXEC (@SQLString);

DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@i INT'
SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + ' VALUES(@i)'

DECLARE @i INT = 1;
WHILE ( @i <= @nRows )
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, @params, @i;
    END
```

Version without executing in loop:

```
....

EXEC (@SQLString);

SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + ' VALUES'

DECLARE @i INT = 1;
WHILE ( @i <= @nRows )
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + '(' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '),'
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END

EXEC(SUBSTRING(@SQLString, 1, LEN(@SQLString) - 1))
```

Version with Tally:

```
....

EXEC (@SQLString);

SET @SQLString = '
;WITH cte AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT (1))) AS RN FROM 
           (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g(ID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) h(ID)
)
INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '
SELECT RN FROM cte WHERE RN <= ' + CAST(@nRows AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXEC(@SQLString)
```

Comment: It may be better to create a string of say 1000 insert statements and then executes it.

Comment: Would be even better if you used a tally/numbers table here instead of looping.

Comment: I suspect that underlying table structure would be more complicated and tallies wont help.

Comment: How could a tally not help when inserting sequential integers?

Comment: I suspect that provided example was simplified to sequential set.

Answer (score 1):

when ever you are using variable in the query you should assign the total query to another variable then execute it as.....

```
DECLARE @sqlstring2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + ' VALUES(@i);'
 exec(@sqlstring2)
```